Excel VBA to list Sheets in selected Workbook and copy listed Sheets to end of Main Workbook
I have a working VBA code present in a Main Workbook which is designed to browse and select Another Workbook and generate a list of names of all Worksheets present in the selected book in the Main Workbook's Sheet(1)'s Column A.
I want to make addition to this VBA code to also Copy all the listed Worksheets of selected Workbook at the end of the Sheets present in Main Workbook.
Sub SelectWorkbookAndListWorksheets()
Dim dialogBox As FileDialog
Set dialogBox = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogOpen)
Dim sheet_name As String
Dim sheet_count As Integer
Dim i As Integer
Dim WS As Worksheet
Dim strPath As String
Dim strName As String

strPath = Application.ThisWorkbook.Path
strName = Application.ThisWorkbook.Name

dialogBox.AllowMultiSelect = False
dialogBox.Title = "Browse & Select Workbook"
dialogBox.InitialFileName = "D:\"
dialogBox.Filters.Clear
dialogBox.Filters.Add "Excel workbooks", "*.xlsx;*.xls;*.xlsm"

If dialogBox.Show = -1 Then
    ActiveSheet.Range("S3").Value = dialogBox.SelectedItems(1)
Else
    End

End If

Set WS = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1)

Workbooks.Open Filename:=Cells(3, 19).Value

sheet_count = Sheets.Count

For i = 1 To sheet_count
    WS.Cells(i, 1) = Sheets(i).Name
Next i

Application.Workbooks.Open (strPath & "\" & strName)

End Sub


Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Read as; I've copied this code, I've no idea how it works, and I want to change it...

The only advice I can give is to record a macro of you doing the task. Then modify/generalize it to your specifications.

I have updated the user's code and wrote the comments -
    Sub SelectWorkbookAndListWorksheets()
Dim dialogBox As FileDialog
Set dialogBox = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogOpen)
Dim sheet_name As String
Dim sheet_count As Integer
Dim i As Integer
Dim WS As Worksheet
Dim strPath As String
Dim strName As String

strPath = Application.ThisWorkbook.Path
strName = Application.ThisWorkbook.Name

dialogBox.AllowMultiSelect = False
dialogBox.Title = "Browse & Select Workbook"
dialogBox.InitialFileName = "C:\Personal"
dialogBox.Filters.Clear
dialogBox.Filters.Add "Excel workbooks", "*.xlsx;*.xls;*.xlsm"

If dialogBox.Show = -1 Then
    ActiveSheet.Range("S3").Value = dialogBox.SelectedItems(1)
Else
    End
End If


Set WS = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1)
Filename = Cells(3, 19).Value
Set wb = Workbooks.Open(Filename)

'** updated code **
counter = 1
For Each sh In wb.Worksheets
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Cells(counter, 2).Value = sh.Name ' this will copy sheet name to first sheet of main workbook
    sh.Copy After:=ThisWorkbook.Sheets(ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Count) ' this line will copy sheet to main workbook
    counter = counter + 1
Next sh  
  '** updated code end**
End Sub


Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
